# Text and images won't center on my page

Tags: css, web, html

I am making my first webpage and I have the elements I want- I can't seem to get them to center on the page. I have tried margin: auto, text-align: center, and lots of toher things. Nothing has worked.

I want the header, an image , and a button at the end of my page, to be a central spine down my page. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
```

```
  <h1 class="text-center"> My tribute to Ami Coxill Moore</h1>
</div>
```

```
<!-- picture of ami here -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4"></div>
          <a href="#add-fastrack"><img class="img-resize img-center img-zero image-border img-responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/Lc5nBon.jpg" alt="Ami laughing at her 26th Birthday"> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {margin-top: 100px;
background-color: #ff69b4;
font-family: "gerogia", serif;
 color: #0000ff;  }


h1 {
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
font-size: 300%;
border: solid;
border-radius: 25px;
align: center;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 40px;
float: center;
max width: 100%;
text-align: center;
marrgin: 0 auto;
float: center;}

div {
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;}

.img-responsive {
margin: 0 auto;}

.img-resize {
max-width: 400px; 
max-height: auto;}
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't have CSS class `img-center`. Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the container text-align

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
```

the div that wraps your element is the responsible to align the element.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class and call it for example `.text-center` and put inside it `text-align: center`,
once you want to center a text just give this class to the container element (**parent element**).

Hope this solve your issue.

```css
body {margin-top: 100px;
background-color: #ff69b4;
font-family: "gerogia", serif;
 color: #0000ff;  }

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
font-size: 300%;
border: solid;
border-radius: 25px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 40px;
max width: 100%;}

div {
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;}

.img-resize {
max-width: 400px; 
max-height: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <h1> My tribute to Ami Coxill Moore</h1>
</div>
<!-- picture of ami here -->
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4"></div>
          <a href="#add-fastrack"><img class="img-resize img-center img-zero image-border img-responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/Lc5nBon.jpg" alt="Ami laughing at her 26th Birthday"> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistake in your code, for example, you must use of `max-width: 100%;` no `max width: 100%;` or `text-align: center;` no `align: center;` value for `float` is `left` or `right` so `float:center` is wrong, and other mistakes.

**see my code:**

```css
body {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #ff69b4;
    font-family: "gerogia", serif;
    color: #0000ff;
}

h1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 300%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.row {
    text-align: center;
}

.row img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center"> My tribute to Ami Coxill Moore</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#add-fastrack"><img class="img-resize img-center img-zero image-border img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDAYrQr9qgT2W00EV_CoCahFki3Vw4lSMNt81k9FCSTXoKT8TY2w" alt="Ami laughing at her 26th Birthday">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```